# Posting id to layer's SQL using laravel (ajax)

Tags: geoserver, wfs, ajax, post

I have done  the following step to post my id

```
function sendRequestToGeoServerWithId(numericId) {

var cqlFilter = "id=" + numericId; // Replace 'id' with the actual attribute name

var geoServerUrl = 'http://202.52.0.116:8080/geoserver/';


var requestData = {
    service: 'WFS',
    version: '2.0.0',
    request: 'GetFeature',
    typeName: 'flownetwork', // Replace with the actual layer name
    outputFormat: 'application/json', // Change to the appropriate format
    CQL_FILTER: cqlFilter // Include the CQL filter here
};


$.ajax({
url: geoServerUrl + 'wfs',
type: 'post', // Use POST method
dataType: 'json', // Change to the appropriate data type
data: requestData,
success: function(response) {
    // Handle the response from GeoServer here
    console.log('Response from GeoServer for numericId ' + numericId + ':', response);
},
error: function(data) {
    console.log('Error in AJAX request to GeoServer for numericId ' + numericId);
}
```

});

```
console.log('Sending request to GeoServer with numericId:', numericId);
```

}

and when i check my network it has this on request a

```
service "WFS"
version "2.0.0"
request "GetFeature"
typeName    "flownetwork"
outputFormat    "application/json"
CQL_FILTER  "id=27"
and in response it has 
type    "FeatureCollection"
features    []
totalFeatures   0
numberMatched   0
numberReturned  0
timeStamp   "2023-10-06T11:01:01.241Z"
crs null
```

Comment: can you add the actual XML you are sending to GeoServer and the relevant part of the GeoServer log

Comment: I don't know about the xml because i'm very new to this and basically i want to pass that id to my geo server layer where there's a sql like this                                                     SELECT * from fnc_get_flow_of_network_upstream('grey_water.drain', %id%, 10)

Comment: Have you created a SQL view?

Comment: yea i have already created a sql view

Comment: did you read the manual? - https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html#parameterizing-sql-views